# Fiona not seeing .shp file as a recognised format

Tags: python, github-actions, shapefile, geopandas, fiona

All of my unittests pass on my local machine, however when I try to use a .yml file to test them every time a pull request is created, there are several failures. An example of one of the error messages is shown below:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

>   ???
E   fiona._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: 'static_data/england_wa_2011_clipped.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.

fiona/_err.pyx:291: CPLE_OpenFailedError
```

My Linux .yml file is below, I have already tried changing around the working directory and it appears to be correct. The file is not corrupted and as it is the same on both VM's I think it is an issue with Fiona. This file also has a corresponding file for testing on a Windows VM however they are spitting out the same error messages and failing the same tests.

```
name: Python Linux application

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ '**' ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          sudo apt-get install libproj-dev proj-data proj-bin
          sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
          sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev
          pip install GDAL==3.2.3
          pip install flake8 pytest Cython numpy pyproj pygeos
          if [ -f requirements-linux.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements-linux.txt; fi
      - name: Lint with flake8
        run: |
          # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
          flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
          # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
          flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest
```

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/Zach10a/seedpod_ground_risk
The branch is CI.

Comment: Can you point us at your github repository? It would be much easier for us to help out if we could clone your code and examine the behavior for ourselves.

Comment: Done! Cheers for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `actions/checkout@v2` action does not, by default, check out files stored using LFS. So while there is file named, for example, `static_data/england_wa_2011_clipped.shp` in your repository, the contents are going to look something like this:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:c60f74e3b8ed753d771378f0b03b7c8e8a84406f413a37f9f5242ac9235a2e6c
size 114084720
```

So Fiona is giving you an accurate error:

```
E   fiona._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: 'static_data/england_wa_2011_clipped.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

You need to instruct the `checkout` action to download files stored in LFS:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true
```